# Python loadarff fails for string attributes

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to load an arff file using Python's 'loadarff' function from scipy.io.arff. The file has string attributes and it is giving the following error.

```
>>> data,meta = arff.loadarff(fpath)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/home/eex608/conda3_envs/PyT3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py", line 805, in loadarff
    return _loadarff(ofile)
  File "/data/home/eex608/conda3_envs/PyT3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/arff/arffread.py", line 838, in _loadarff
    raise NotImplementedError("String attributes not supported yet, sorry")
NotImplementedError: String attributes not supported yet, sorry
```

How to read the arff successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SciPy's loadarff converts containings of arff file into NumPy array, it does not support strings as attributes.
In 2020, you can use [liac-arff](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff) package.

```
import arff
data = arff.load(open('your_document.arff', 'r'))
```

However, make sure your arff document does not contain inline comments after a meaningful text.
So there won't be such inputs:

```
@ATTRIBUTE class {F,A,L,LF,MN,O,PE,SC,SE,US,FT,PO} %Check and make sure that FT and PO should be there
```

Delete or move comment to the next line.

I'd got such mistake in one document and it took some time to figure out what's wrong.